# Separated Status / UK Work Permit

Tags: united-kingdom, working-visas

I am applying for a UK work permit. My marital status is "Separated" (I am in the process of getting a divorce from my wife). Will this status impact my application for a Work Permit to UK?

Comment: I can't see why this would have much significance in the UK - it shouldn't be a problem. Your question really belongs on [expatriates.se] where they are better placed to answer it. I suggest you delete this and repost it there.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that your marital status should not affect your Visa application unless your ex-wife is in the UK, was in the UK or is a citizen of the country.